# Has suppressing CS8632 any bad consequences?

Tags: c#, nullable

I'm working on a codebase that is not yet `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`. There is a vague notion that we will activate nullablity sometime soonish.

While writing code I'm sometimes tempted to use nullability operators (e.g. `void Foo(string? stringOrNull) {}`). Mostly to explicitly mark that this argument is intended to accept null and that the implementation does/should respect that. Obviously I won't get any potential wrong-usage compiler-warning befits until nullability is activated. But at least I have noted my intent at the implementation site and whenever nullability is activated it should be picked up.

But of cause, for now, I get the compiler warning `CS8632: The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' annotations context`.

Can I just suppress that or are there any unintended consequences?

Comment: Feels a bit dirty to me, though I don't have a good reason. I'm pretty sure the IL is the same with or without the `?`. Can't you just add `#nullable enable` in the files where you use it? It should make the future migration to use it a lot smoother.

Comment: @DavidG hm, that's a good alternative.